# Unity how to find Vive controller game objects?

Tags: unity-game-engine, virtual-reality

New to VR development and relatively new to Unity. Anyone know a good/best practice way to find the game object for the left and right controllers?

Comment: Start from here : https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=rfcX07uiQmA

Comment: If you name the gameobjects something appropriate then that shouldn't be an issue.

Answer (score 0):

You can find them in the [Vive SDK package for Unity](https://www.assetstore.unity3d.com/en/#!/content/32647).
It does with some sample scenes and controller models are included.

If you want to know their destination path- just pause the game once SteamVR is up and running, select left or right controller and check model's mesh renderer component - it will point you directly to the place in project where mesh is saved.